# How to convert user input string to pig latin?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Im trying to convert a user entered string that starts with a consonant to pig latin buy moving all the consonants to the end of the word till the word starts with a vowel, and then adding "ay" to the end of the word. I have a for loop that's supposed to do this, but for some reason, it outputs nothing. What am i doing wrong here? Im stumped.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class two {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a word");
        Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pigLatin = word.nextLine();
        while (!pigLatin.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            if (isVowel(pigLatin.charAt(0))) {
                pigLatin = (pigLatin + "way");
                System.out.println(pigLatin);
            } 
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < pigLatin.length(); i++) {
                    char firstChar = pigLatin.charAt(0); 
                    pigLatin = pigLatin.substring(1);
                    pigLatin = pigLatin + firstChar;
                    if (i >= pigLatin.length())
                    {
                        pigLatin = pigLatin + "ay";
                        System.out.println(pigLatin);
                    }
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Please enter a word");
            pigLatin = word.nextLine();
        }
        word.close();

    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        char v = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        if (v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u') {
            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Not that this solves anything, but: `if(condition){return true;}else{return false;}` can be simplified to `return condition;`.

Comment: Working with char arrays (`myString.toCharArray()`) is probably a better approach to working directly with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a less than or equal <= on the i otherwise i is never greater than or equal to pigLatin.length().

```
                for (int i = 0; i <= pigLatin.length(); i++) {
                    char firstChar = pigLatin.charAt(0); 
                    pigLatin = pigLatin.substring(1);
                    pigLatin = pigLatin + firstChar;
                    if (i >= pigLatin.length())
                    {
                        System.out.println(pigLatin);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Of course this is not all that you need to change, but it at least gets you output which is what you wanted ;)

Comment: hahaha i feel so stupid. thank you so much! i got it working :)))

Answer (score 0):

your for loop condition is

```
i < pigLatin.length()
```

and you said in if

```
if(i >= pigLatin.length()){....}
```

so this condition will never be true , for that reason there is no output,

see below code ,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author rahmat waisi
 */
public class PigLatin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (true) {
                // System.out.print("Please enter a word: , Enter [ quit ] for exit : ");
                String pigLatin = scanner.nextLine();
                if (pigLatin.equals("quit")) {
                    break;
                }
                if (isVowel(pigLatin.charAt(0))) {
                    pigLatin += "ay";
                    System.out.println(pigLatin);
                } else {
                    String output = "";
                    int separation_index = findFirstVowel(pigLatin);
                    if (separation_index ==-1) {
                        System.out.println(pigLatin+"ay");
                        continue;
                    }
                    output+= pigLatin.substring(separation_index);
                    output+= pigLatin.substring(0, separation_index) + "ay";
                    System.out.println(output);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        char v = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        return v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u';
    }

    private static int findFirstVowel(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (isVowel(str.charAt(i))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

here is some input:

```
pig
banana
trash
happy
duck
glove
eat
omelet
are
ffff
quit
```

and their output is:

```
igpay
ananabay
ashtray
appyhay
uckday
oveglay
eatay
omeletay
areay
ffffay
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class two {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a word");
        Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pigLatin = word.nextLine();
        while (!pigLatin.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            if (isVowel(pigLatin.charAt(0))) {
                pigLatin = (pigLatin + "way");
                System.out.println(pigLatin);
            } 
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < pigLatin.length(); i++) {
                    char firstChar = pigLatin.charAt(0); 
                    pigLatin = pigLatin.substring(1);
                    pigLatin = pigLatin + firstChar;
                    if (i >= pigLatin.length())
                    {
                        pigLatin = pigLatin + "ay";
                        System.out.println(pigLatin);
                    }
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Please enter a word");
            pigLatin = word.nextLine();
        }
        word.close();

    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        char v = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        if (v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u') {
            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).